# knockoutjs call a click method within a with

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have added a click method within a with template.

I keep getting an error that
Uncaught ReferenceError: myMethod is not defined
but Person clearly has that method

```
Person = (data) ->
    name = ko.observable(data.name)
    lname = ko.observable(data.lname)    
    myMethod = (data) -> 
        console.log 'person.myMethod' 
    test= -> 
        console.log 'person.test' 
    name:name
    lname:lname    
    myMethod:myMethod
    test:test
```

and this is the template

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <h4>Person</h4>
    <ul  >
        <li data-bind="with:person">
            <span data-bind="text: name"> </span> 
            <span data-bind="text: lname"> </span>  
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: function() {   myMethod($data) }" >CLICK </a>  
        </li> 
    </ul > 
</div>
```

I don't understand how to call myMethod on the Person object while inside the anonymous template 
I have tried things like

```
$parent.person.myMethod
$root.person.myMethod
this.myMethod
person.myMethod
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eiu165/a7uTM/3/

many thanks

**EDIT**
fixed to add the method name to myMethod

Comment: At least in the fiddle, you're never defining "myMethod".

Comment: your right I got confused when making it here is my solution. the main problem is when creating the person object. http://jsfiddle.net/eiu165/hbpBd/#base person(Person($.parseJSON(data)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems in your code:

1. You don't have a `myMethod` but a `methodCall` method so `myMethod:myMethod` should be `myMethod:methodCall`
2. Altough there is a `myMethod` on `Person` but **you don't have a Person object** in your `person = ko.observable()`.

   Because with the expression `person($.parseJSON(data))` you only pass in the raw data. So what you need is to create a `Person` with `person(Person($.parseJSON(data)))`

Here is a fixed [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/fGtTp/).

Comment: thanks great  person(Person($.parseJSON(data)))  was key to make a Person object, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't pass a function or data to a click. Just pass the method name and pull the needed data inside of the view model.

```
data-bind="click: myMethod"
```

Comment: gives an error Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: myMethod is not defined;
Bindings value: click: myMethod   http://jsfiddle.net/eiu165/a7uTM/5/

Comment: i dont know where `myMethod` is defined.